# Fabric ssh asks for password but no key failure in debug output

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, fabric, paramiko

I'm trying to use Fabric3 to automatically ssh into a Linux box without entering a password from my Windows 7 PC. I'm using openssl keys that I generated with puttygen from the .ppk file that I usually use to log in with PuTTY. My python script is the following:

```
paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG) #Added for ssh key debugging

env.host_string = "#.#.#.#" 
with settings(user='root', key_filename='C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\My_id.pub'):  
    run('ifconfig eth1', stderr=output)
```

The output (with debug) is:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\Testing\TestRig\python_scripts>python ssh_login.py
[#.#.#.#] run: ifconfig eth1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x3087070
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.1.2
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc',
'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-md5
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for #.#.#.#: b'23df3f11b9dc46423a03afd08bae8cf9'
[#.#.#.#] Login password for 'root':
```

The last line prompts for a password to be entered. I do not want that; this is what I am trying to fix. Looking at some similar questions on SO, the paramiko debug output usually says something along the lines of "Authentication Failed". However, I don't see that here.

My best guess is that the public key is okay, but there's some additional setting I'm missing in the Python script.

Comment: `key_filename='C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\My_id.pub'` I don't know if this is your only problem, but you should be using the private key file here, not the public key file.

Comment: Thank you, I think that was part of it. The other part of it was that the box I was logging into had a banner upon login. For some reason it's expecting me to pass the banner password as a setting AND via the run command. Very strange.